# Какой дистрибутив линукса выбрать для последней версии Monodevelop?

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop, ide

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой дистрибутив линукса выбрать, чтобы на него без лишних танцев с бубном можно было установить Mono и MonoDevelop **последних версий**. С debian намучался, я к тому же новичок в linux, 2 дня угрохал в попытках поставить актуальные версии (

вот например на debian: MonoDevelop не запускается из консоли ( и из гуи тоже)

[image]

хотя эти Mono.Addins установлены:
[image]

В общем подскажите на каком дистрибутиве и как установить моно и монодевелоп последних версий, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- openSUSE: [3.0.3.4](http://software.opensuse.org/package/monodevelop) в «родном» репозитории, там же рядом 3.0.5-git, так же есть [trunk](http://monodevelop.com/Download/Trunk_Builds). Так что если нужно вот прямо с пылу с жару — вариант.
- Arch: [3.0.3-5.2](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/monodevelop/), на AUR есть monodevelop-git ([PKGBUILD](https://gist.github.com/3187464)).
- Gentoo: [3.0.2-r1](http://gentoo-portage.com/dev-util/monodevelop), но [ebuild](http://gpo.zugaina.org/AJAX/Ebuild/2168155/View) тривиально переименовывается и (по идее) должен работать для более новых версий.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu например.

- [Mono for Ubuntu](http://www.mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Ubuntu);
- [Building MonoDevelop on Ubuntu](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Building_MonoDevelop_on_Ubuntu).

Comment: По второй ссылке как-то все не по-человечески делают. Как будто не под Debian, а под слакой сидят.

По человечески, разумеется мне, надо взять свежие исходники monodevelop (3.0.4 или trunk), сунуть туда `debian/*` от 3.0.4, поправить `debian/changelog` и сказать что-то в духе `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us`. Возможно, правда, что-то с ходу не взлетит и надо будет потрогать правила (скажем, добавить зависимость в `debian/control`) или удалить debian-specific патчи, которые уже не накладываются на новую версию (в `debian/patches`, если мейнтейнер не навелосипедировал).

Comment: Можно сделать проще. Достаточно лишь скачать пакет для убунты. http://monodevelop.com/Download

Comment: в пакете для убунты написано "Packages for MonoDevelop 3.0.4.7 not yet available. The latest available version is MonoDevelop 2.6.0.1"